# подсчет объектов на изображении c#

Tags: c#, изображения

Есть бинарное изображение. (Белый фон с черными пятнами).
Необходимо вывести номер каждого пятна и его площадь.
Алгоритм понимаю, но из-за недостатка опыта ума не приложу, как реализовать это на с#.
Т.е., алгоритм рекурсивной разметки связных областей

Comment: Что конкретно мешает это реализовать? Задайте вопрос более конкретно.

Comment: Можно использовать [алгоритм заливки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433537/184217).